# cast exception android.widget.TextView

Tags: java, android, fatal-error, classcastexception

I am new to android developement, while trying to create an editable TextView I ran into the following exception.

Here is the full stack trace of the exception

```
09-17 01:25:14.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8436): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 01:25:14.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8436): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.timer/com.example.timer.TimerHomeActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
09-17 01:25:14.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
09-17 01:25:14.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
09-17 01:25:14.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-17 01:25:14.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8436):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
09-17 01:25:14.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8436):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-17 01:25:14.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8436):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-17 01:25:14.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
09-17 01:25:14.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8436):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-17 01:25:14.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8436):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-17 01:25:14.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8436):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
09-17 01:25:14.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8436):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
09-17 01:25:14.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8436):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-17 01:25:14.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8436): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
09-17 01:25:14.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8436):     at com.example.timer.TimerHomeActivity.onCreate(TimerHomeActivity.java:23)
09-17 01:25:14.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8436):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-17 01:25:14.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
09-17 01:25:14.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8436):     ... 11 more
```

This is the Code:

```
public class TimerHomeActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

   public void onClick(View v) {
     TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer_1);
     tv.setText("Hi");
   }
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.timer_home);
      Button timer1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.timer_1);
      timer1.setOnClickListener(this);
   }  
}
```

Comment: TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer_1);

Button timer1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.timer_1);

maybe this is the problem? both Button and TextView have same id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your resource IDs. You are loading the same resource ID twice, once converting it to a `TextView` and once to a `Button`:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer_1);
```

and

```
Button timer1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.timer_1);
```

It should correspond to one widget and the other will throw a `ClassCastException`.

Since the exception is occuring when starting the activity, the statement causing the exception should be the one in the `onCreate` method. This means resource `timer_1` is not a `Button` but a `TextView` (as indicated in the exception message which by the way seems to be truncated in your post).

Comment: The problem seems to be with                                         Button timer1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.timer_1);                     even when                                                                          TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer_1);                   is removed, the same exception is thrown.

Comment: It would help if you post more of the exception stack trace.

Comment: I have posted the full stack trace.

Comment: @Jasher so that's because timer_1 is a textview then, so when you cast it to a Button you get the exception. Check timer_1 in your resource xmls and make sure you are using the correct ids-

Comment: @rupps timer_1 is a textview thats why i cast it into a button to listen for clicks. textview can be cast into button can't it??

Comment: you **can't** cast a `TextView` to a `Button`, however, you can add a `clicklistener` to a `TextView` (or to any `View`), or cast a `Button` to a `TextView` (`Button` extends `TextView`)